# A good way to create and edit PyQt elements in one line

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

this is my first stackoverflow post so I hope I'm doing this right. I'm working on a gui in python using PyQt6 and I'm doing this in pure code as I prefer the control over the Qt designer. As I'm adding elements to the gui I'm noticing my code bloating and getting harder to navigate. Here is [a picture of an element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJojE.png) and the code I used to generate it:

```
lbl_size = QLabel("Size:")
lbl_size.setObjectName("lbl_size")

line_height = QLineEdit()
line_height.setObjectName("line_heigth")
line_height.setFixedWidth(40)

lbl_by = QLabel("by")
lbl_by.setObjectName("lbl_by")

line_width = QLineEdit()
line_width.setObjectName("line_width")
line_width.setFixedWidth(40)

combo_3d = QComboBox()
combo_3d.setObjectName("combo_3d")
combo_3d.addItems("2D", "3D")

hlayout_size = QHBoxLayout()
hlayout_size.addWidget(lbl_size)
hlayout_size.addWidget(line_height)
hlayout_size.addWidget(lbl_by)
hlayout_size.addWidget(line_width)
hlayout_size.addWidget(combo_3d)
hlayout_size.addStretch()
hlayout_size.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

What I like about this approach is that is quite legible and clear. What I dislike is that adding elements in such a way starts to add up, fast. I'm at a point where I feel bad for having such a large init function for some pages in my gui.

My main gripe is that I need to use functions for editing my widgets and layouts, rather than passing arguments into the creation of the widget for example. I made an attempt at solving this by creating custom classes that do take arguments to set up my widgets and layouts the way I want in only one line. These are examples of some custom classes I made:

```
class CQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text=None, obj_name=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        if text:
            self.setText(text)
        if obj_name:
            self.setObjectName(obj_name)


class CQLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, placeholder_text=None, width=None, obj_name=None):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self)
        if placeholder_text:
            self.setPlaceholderText(placeholder_text)
        if width:
            self.setFixedWidth(width)
        if obj_name:
            self.setObjectName(obj_name)


class CQComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, items=None, obj_name=None):
        QComboBox.__init__(self)
        if items:
            self.addItems(items)
        if obj_name:
            self.setObjectName(obj_name)


class CQHBoxLayout(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, items=None, stretch=False, margins=None, obj_name=None):
        QHBoxLayout.__init__(self)
        if items:
            for item in items:
                if isinstance(item, QWidget):
                    self.addWidget(item)
                elif isinstance(item, QLayout):
                    self.addLayout(item)
        if stretch:
            self.addStretch()
        if margins:
            self.setContentsMargins(margins)
        if obj_name:
            self.setObjectName(obj_name)
```

With these classes the code I need to generate the exact same element as before is the following:

```
lbl_size = CQLabel(text="Size:", obj_name="lbl_size")
line_height = CQLineEdit(width=40, obj_name="line_height")
lbl_by = CQLabel(text="by", obj_name="lbl_by")
line_width = CQLineEdit(width=40, obj_name="line_width")
combo_3d = CQComboBox(items=("2D", "3D"), obj_name="combo_3d")

hlayout_size = CQHBoxLayout(items=(lbl_size, line_height, lbl_by, line_width, combo_3d), stretch=True,
                            margins=(10, 10, 10, 10), obj_name="hlayout_size")
```

These kinds of statements are a bit harder to interpret at a glance than the straight foward function calls from before, but for me this works fully as intended. This way of building the gui gets better as I'm adding more elements and making more edits to my widgets.

My 'problem' now, is that this way I built these classes (mainly relying on if statements) is not something I've seen before and makes me wonder if it is a good approach at all. Seeing as I have almost no experience working on big projects I would really appreciate some comments on my approach. Is it good? Is it bad? Am I totally missing a more easy approach? Thanks for any help in advance!

(NB: I'm not focused on one-liners, just looking for a way to combat code bloat)

Comment: I would suggest to not create your own derived classes but just defining helper functions that take all the arguments, create a new instance of the original class, do the additional calls as required by the given arguments and then return the created instance.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow! Usually questions should deal with a specific problem, not ask for opinions. So it might very well happen that your question will get closed for that reason.

Comment: @SebDieBln you are theoretically correct, but this is one of the rare cases for which the answer actually exists, and it's because the implementation already provides it, so there's no "best approach", as there's the *existing one*.

Comment: @SebDieBln Thanks for the tip of using helper functions! Might not be the correct approach here apparantly, but good to know. Would it still be 'normal' to use if-statements to check whether an argument was actually given in such a case? And thanks for your other advice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyQt natively supports setting properties in the class constructor using keyword arguments; in fact, it also allows direct signal connections (see [the documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html)).

For example:

```py
label = QLabel('Hello', objectName='someLabel', font=QFont('Verdana'))
lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText='type something')
button = QPushButton('click me', cliked=self.buttonClicked)
```

Note that this can only work:

- for QObject subclasses (so, for instance, it's not possible for QStandardItem);
- with writable *Qt properties*, if you want custom properties, use the pyqtProperty decorator;
- using the exact property name (not the function getter, which might be different);

Also note that you should only set object names when you know that you'll need them (usually for later `findChild*` calls on dynamically created objects, or specific QSS selectors, or data serialization, like window settings), otherwise it's generally useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I find the documentation hard to navigate sometimes when looking for what properties a specific QObject has and how to know which keyword argument to use when creating an instance. The fact that PyCharm doesn't recognize valid keyword arguments is also not helping. But this way does not allow you to, for example, set a fixed width for QLineEdit or add multiple widgets or layouts to QBoxLayout upon creation, correct?

Comment: Hard to navigate? The Qt docs always have a section for the properties of classes (for instance, see the [QWidget property list](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties)). PyCharm cannot recognize them because they're dynamically accessed through the QMetaObject. Setting the fixed size is not possible like this because it's not a property (but you can set a maximum and minimum width, which is exactly the same), adding multiple widgets is not possible for the very same reason. As noted in the comment above, you should make helper functions for this kind of things, instead of adding classes.

Comment: This helps a lot. I've mainly been looking in the PyQt documentation, but the Qt docs seem more extensive and helpful in some cases. And thanks for the further explanation as well. Sometimes its hard to learn something on your own, so the tips, explanations and nudges in the right direction are very appreciated!

Comment: @ClovisBray You're welcome. Consider that in 99% of the cases the PyQt documentation is just based on an empty template; this aspect might seem incoherent, but the fact is that having the whole documentation there would be quite redundant, as it would be just a plain copy of the original Qt api docs, so you should only consider it for additional research and to check for argument signatures or returned types (for which you can also use the interactive python shell with `help(module.class.function)`. For all the rest, always consider the standard C++ Qt docs as main reference.